# GNU GCC: How to compile google-pertools such that it does not require @GLIBCXX_3.4

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, linker, freebsd, libstdc++

I compiled the library and checked the symbols using readelf command, I got

```
$ readelf -s ./.libs/libtcmalloc.so.5 | grep GLIB

94: 0000000000000000    32 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _ZNSs4_Rep20_S_empty_rep_@GLIBCXX_3.4 (5)
```

I want to compile the library such a way that @GLIBCXX_3.4 gets omitted.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do that is build with an older GCC which doesn't use versioned symbols, or recompile GCC itself with `--disable-symbol-versioning` and then recompile the library with that new GCC.

Why do you want this?

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I need to profile an executable with google perftools. This executable links itself against a tailored libstdc++.so which comes without symbol versioning. To get the executable working, I cannot link the libtcmalloc.so against standard libstdc++.so, so I need to rebuild libtcmalloc.so without without ABI version information.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. Why do you need a library without versioned symbols?

Comment: because I am getting the error "/usr/local/lib/gcc43/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4' not found" when I try to run my code under google perf tool. Actually I want to compile libtcmalloc.so such that I does not depend on "GLIBCXX_3.4".

Comment: I recompiled gcc with --disable-symbol-versioning and then rebuilt library file with newly compiled gcc. I still see version string in the library I built. Is there something I missed out?

Comment: Sorry, I think I remembered the option wrong, a quick search indicates --disable-symvers but I can't check right now